# Quitting due to lack of engagement

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, quitting

I'm working as a software developer in the current company for three years. My engagement on projects is quite low (like only 25% of time I worked on customers projects). Most of the time I spend working on internal projects that unfortunately lack good code quality control and management in general or I'm learning new technologies.

What did I try so far? First of all, I never gave any ultimatum to my employer and they generally have a good opinion about me. I was dispatching this issue toward our managers. However, our office is getting projects from the other office of our company, so they cannot control when we are getting a new project. Our boss is totally fine with having people off projects for a long periods.

Although my current job is very stable and the company itself provides a lot of bonuses, I'm afraid that the current situation could inflict significant damage on my career (if it isn't already) since I do not feel like I'm advancing.

This is the only reason why I want to quit. How can I do it in the most professional way? As said, without "burning bridges".

Comment: FWIW, "or I'm learning new technologies", there are plenty of questions here on Workplace from people leaving jobs because they don't get to do this

Comment: @cdkMoose I'm perfectly aware of that. Thanks for pointing tho. But what's the point of the game if you're constantly sitting on the bench.

Comment: you are improving your chances to get a new job by having a broader skill set, which is more than we can say for the poor developer on the bench who isn't learning anything new

Comment: @cdkMoose "you are improving your chances to get a new job by having a broader skill set" - And that's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy one.

You quietly look for a new job.  You fill out applications, you attend interviews, you negotiate a starting salary and benefits, and you get a written offer with no restrictions.

You then submit a very short and simple resignation letter:

> [today's date]
>
> Dear Manager
>
> I am resigning my position at Company A effective [date].
>
> Sincerely,
>
> user86327

You are not obligated to give a reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And what if they ask for a reason? How to politely refuse to answer? Just to go with: "I refuse to answer". How that can affect an outcome of their general opinion about me?

Comment: Just because they ask for a reason doesn't automatically mean they're entitled to one.  You could either be vague ("the position looks promising") or just shut down the line of questioning ("my reasons for a career change are personal and not open to discussion or debate").

Comment: Or you can say something generic like "It was time to take on new challenges, and I thank you so much for the opportunities to learn that I have received here."

Comment: The key here is **to not quit** until you find another role.